# Why does a high-value input prevent an array from using the actual input value in C?

Tags: arrays, c, scanf, 64-bit, limit

I'm making a function that takes a value using scanf_s and converts that into a binary value. The function works perfectly... until I put in a really high value.

I'm also doing this on VS 2019 in x64 in C

And in case it matters, I'm using

```
main(int argc, char* argv[])
```

for the main function.

Since I'm not sure what on earth is happening, here's the whole code I guess.

```
BinaryGet()
{
// Declaring lots of stuff
int x, y, z, d, b, c;
int counter = 0;
int doubler = 1;
int getb;
int binarray[2000] = { 0 };

// I only have to change things to 1 now, am't I smart?
int binappend[2000] = { 0 };


// Get number
printf("Gimme a number\n");
scanf_s("%d", &getb);



// Because why not
printf("\n");

// Get the amount of binary places to be used (how many times getb divides by 2)
x = getb;
while (x > 1)
{
    d = x;
    counter += 1;

    // Tried x /= 2, gave me infinity loop ;(
    x = d / 2;
}


// Fill the array with binary values (i.e. 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, etc)
for (b = 1; b <= counter; b++)
{
    binarray[b] = doubler * 2;

    doubler *= 2;

    
}


// Compare the value of getb to binary values, subtract and repeat until getb = 0)
c = getb;
for (y = counter; c >= 1; y--)
{   

    // Printing c at each subtraction

    
    printf("\n%d\n", c);

    // If the value of c (a temp variable) compares right to the binary value, subtract that binary value
    // and put a 1 in that spot in binappend, the 1 and 0 list
    if (c >= binarray[y])
    {

        c -= binarray[y];
        binappend[y] += 1;
    }


    // Prevents buffer under? runs
    if (y <= 0)
    {
        break;
    }
}

// Print the result
for (z = 0; z <= counter; z++)
{
    printf("%d", binappend[z]);
}
}
```

The problem is that when I put in the value 999999999999999999 (18 digits) it just prints 0 once and ends the function. The value of the digits doesn't matter though, 18 ones will have the same result.

However, when I put in 17 digits, it gives me this:

```
99999999999999999

// This is the input value after each subtraction
1569325055

495583231

495583231

227147775

92930047

25821183

25821183

9043967

655359

655359

655359

655359

131071

131071

131071

65535

32767

16383

8191

4095

2047

1023

511

255

127

63

31

15

7

3

1


// This is the binary
1111111111111111100100011011101
```

The binary value it gives me is 31 digits. I thought that it was weird that at 32, a convenient number, it gimps out, so I put in the value of the 32nd binary place minus 1 (2,147,483,647) and it worked. But adding 1 to that gives me 0.

Changing the type of array (unsigned int and long) didn't change this. Neither did changing the value in the brackets of the arrays. I tried searching to see if it's a limit of scanf_s, but found nothing.

I know for sure (I think) it's not the arrays, but probably something dumb I'm doing with the function. Can anyone help please? I'll give you a long-distance high five.

Comment: Did you change `getb`?

Comment: The first chapters of any C programming book typically address numerical limits of the various integer types. I'd start there.

Comment: Changing getb didn't work either. Thanks for reminding me though, I totally forgot that variable

Comment: Of course, Lundin, I know the difference between int, unsigned int, and long. If you read my post, you'll find my knowledge of integers is most likely not the problem.

Comment: @PupperGump I read the question, `%d` always means `int`. `long` is same size as `int` on Windows, 32 bits. With 2^31-1 max value for signed. `%lld` and `long long` is another story though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is indeed related to the power-of-two size of the number you've noticed, but it's in this call:

```c
scanf_s("%d", &getb);
```

The `%d` argument means it is reading into a signed integer, which on your platform is probably 32 bits, and since it's signed it means it can go up to 2³¹-1 in the positive direction.

The conversion specifiers used by `scanf()` and related functions can accept larger sizes of data types though. For example `%ld` will accept a `long int`, and `%lld` will accept a `long long int`. Check the data type sizes for your platform, because a `long int` and an `int` might actually be the same size (32 bits) eg. on Windows.

So if you use `%lld` instead, you should be able to read larger numbers, up to the range of a `long long int`, but make sure you change the target (`getb`) to match! Also if you're not interested in negative numbers, let the type system help you out and use an unsigned type: `%llu` for an `unsigned long long`.

Some details:

1. If `scanf` or its friends fail, the value in `getb` is indeterminate ie. uninitialised, and reading from it is *undefined behaviour* (UB). UB is an extremely common source of bugs in C, and you want to avoid it. Make sure your code only reads from `getb` if `scanf` tells you it worked.
2. In fact, in general it is not possible to avoid UB with `scanf` unless you're in complete control of the input (eg. you wrote it out previously with some other, bug free, software). While you can check the return value of `scanf` and related functions (it will return the number of fields it converts), its behaviour is undefined if, say, a field is too large to fit into the data type you have for it.
3. There's a lot more detail on [`scanf` etc. here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf).
4. To avoid problems with not knowing what size an `int` is, or if a `long int` is different on this platform or that, there is also the [header `stdint.h`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer) which defines integer types of a specific width eg. `int64_t`. These *also* have macros for use with `scanf()` like `SCNd64`. These are available from C99 onwards, but note that Windows' support of C99 in its compilers is incomplete and may not include this.
5. Don't be so hard on yourself, you're not dumb, C is a hard language to master and doesn't follow modern idioms that have developed since it was first designed.

Comment: The **only** platform where that brain-dead `scanf_s` is actively used is Windows and in there `long int` is **always** 32 bits wide, hence your suggestion fixes nothing.

Comment: `scanf_s` has been in the C standard since C11 I think, and it's not out of the question that it would appear outside the Windows ecosystem at this point eg. someone new to C might find it and use it, or a lecturer or textbook might suggest it. Since they're not using any of the conversion specifiers where it matters, the API is identical to `scanf` anyway.

Comment: `scanf_s` is not part of the C11 standard proper, it is an optional annex that was not implemented as is by *anyone*, as far as I know. The only platform that has `scanf_s` (whose behaviour is different from the standard) that a newbie could come across is the Microsoft Visual C++, and there `long int` is always 32 bits wide and therefore not capable of storing any numbers that `int` wouldn't be.

Comment: I've edited my answer to have a more detail around that.

Comment: I don't want to be brain-dead, is there a better way to get an integer?

Comment: @PupperGump it depends on your constraints. If you have to stick with standards-conforming C, probably not. There is [`atoi()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/atoi) and so on, but their API also has quirks you need to be aware of (eg. a return value of 0 can mean both failure and that the text said "0", plus UB on out-of-range values). If you know you're only targeting one platform/operating system, you can use their library functions eg. Windows and GNU might have extra string parsing features.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Also, changing the scanf type didn't change the outcome. Looks like scanf has that limit I suppose.

Comment: @PupperGump it would also be possible to use a 3rd party parsing or regex library eg. PCRE. These require more learning (and you need to learn how to link to them or integrate them into your project) but usually have a more consistent API. I'd say they're more for real-world projects than learning exercises though.

Comment: @PupperGump did you change the type of `x`, `d` and `getb` as well?

Comment: @detly When I do that, it gives me weird negatives. I'm guessing that's because the signed bit is gone? But everything is long long int and this happens 

'2147483648


-2147483648

0

-1073741824

-1610612736

-1879048192

....

-2147483646
11111111111111111111111111111111'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228396/discussion-between-detly-and-pupper-gump).

Comment: Re “In this case, it will return 0 if the first field is too large to fit into a signed integer, so you can detect that and handle it as an error”: Why do you think it will return 0? C 2018 K.3.5.3.4 says `scanf_s` is equivalent to `fscanf_s` with `stdin` interposed. K.3.5.3.2 4 says `fscanf_s` is equivalent to `fscanf` with certain exceptions. For `fscanf`, 7.21.6.2 says “… if the result of the conversion cannot be represented in the object, the behavior is undefined,” and I do not see any relevant exceptions.

Comment: I also see nothing regarding this in [Microsoft’s documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/scanf-s-scanf-s-l-wscanf-s-wscanf-s-l?view=msvc-160).

Comment: @EricPostpischil From the document you linked: *Returns the number of fields successfully converted and assigned. The return value doesn't include fields that were read but not assigned. A return value of 0 indicates no fields were assigned.* I assume there's something similar in the standard, but as I don't have a copy on this machine I can't check. But [my linked resource](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) also says *Number of receiving arguments successfully assigned (which may be zero in case a matching failure occurred before the first receiving argument was assigned)*

Comment: @EricPostpischil Are we perhaps disagreeing here because of the vague boundary between return-as-in-the-keyword "return values" and return-as-in-out-parameter-pointer "return values"? I meant the former.

Comment: @detly: When the result of the conversion cannot be represented in the object, the behavior is undefined. This is not a matching failure (the input string matches the expected format); it is a conversion error. The resulting behavior is undefined. There is no definition of what is put into the object or what is returned as the function value because the behavior is undefined.

Comment: (Testing `scanf` with Apple Clang and Apple’s library returns 1 in the case I tested. So either there is a bug in Apple’s software in this regard or I have overlooked something in the documentation for `scanf_s` that would make it different from `scanf` in this regard.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil I see what you're saying now. Yes. Some implementations are non-compliant and backtrack eg. numeric strings to the point where there was a match. I don't know if Apple's libc is one of them.

Comment: @EricPostpischil is it correct to say, then, that there is actually no way to avoid UB with `scanf` unless you absolutely control the format of the input and know the potential target platforms?

Comment: @detly: Yes, with the conversion specifiers that involve scanning values that might not fit, there is no way to avoid undefined behavior without sanitizing the input first. it is not non-compliant to reject a numeric string because it is too large because the fact that the behavior is not defined by the standard means that any behavior is compliant.

Comment: @EricPostpischil so I suppose the answer to "what is a reasonable way to parse an integer in C" is "find a 3rd party parser".

Comment: I didn't realize the behavior of `scanf` on overflow was *undefined*.  What a mess.  I wonder why it wasn't specified as unspecified? [Answering my own question: probably because on some hardware numeric overflow might trap, but exhaustively pre-checking for the possibility would slow every `scanf` call down.]

Comment: I would like to point out to the original asker that if they're ever feeling dumb because of C again, they can remember that *at least* two >10k rep users learnt something on the back of their innocent question about `scanf`.